# How to define a function without arguments in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to define a function which returns a random number:

```
gnuplot> rnd() = int(rand(0)*2**24)
         ^
         invalid command
```

---

I need add a parameter `x` to stop the error message:

```
gnuplot> rnd(x) = int(rand(0)*2**24)
```

---

Is it possible to define a function without parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that is possible (look at the syntax for functions in `help user-defined`).  As far as I can tell -- using `rand` is the only time when this is useful -- In all other cases your "function" would just evaluate to a constant.  I'm guessing the gnuplot devs just haven't thought of this (interesting) corner case, or they didn't think it useful enough to implement.

I hope that I'm wrong about this and somebody else comes along and proves it, but I don't think I am.  I think the easiest workaround it to just pass a parameter as you've already mentioned.  If you really don't like that, you could use a macro:

```
set macro
rnd="(int(rand(0)*2**24))"
print 5+@rnd
```